# Function overloading, problem with arguments

Tags: typescript, overloading

In this code declaring several overloading functions:

```
export function rect(a: Point, b: Point): Rect;
export function rect(a: Point, b: number|Point, c?: number): Rect;
export function rect(a: number|Point, b: number|Point, c?: number, d?: number ) {return new Rect(a,b,c,d);}
rect( 1,1,1, 1)   // ts: "Expected 2-3 arguments, but got 4.ts(2554)"
```

Typescript complains in the 4th arg. I couldn't figure what is wrong here. If I add one more overload with one more arg:

```
export function rect(a: Point, b: Point): Rect;
export function rect(a: Point, b: number|Point, c?: number): Rect;
export function rect(a: number|Point, b: number|Point, c?: number, d?: number ): Rect ;
export function rect(a: number|Point, b: number|Point, c?: number, d?: number, e?: number ): Rect {return new Rect(a,b,c,d);}
rect( 1,1,1, 1)
```

ts does NOT complain (it gives the same error if I add the 5th arg to the call to rect)

What's wrong?

Comment: Function implementation must meet all overload deninitions. If you need more parameteres, add another overload

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last overload signature is the implementation signature and is not visible to the outside. If you want to have that interface public you will need to duplicate it:

```
export function rect(a: Point, b: Point): Rect;
export function rect(a: Point, b: number | Point, c?: number): Rect;
export function rect(a: number | Point, b: number | Point, c?: number, d?: number): Rect;
export function rect(a: number | Point, b: number | Point, c?: number, d?: number) {
    return new Rect(a, b, c, d);
}
```